# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, visual-studio-2013

> Server Error in '/' Application.

---

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Framework.SharePoint.WebParts.CustomFieldTypes.PreFilledUrlLookupFieldControl.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +1379    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +94
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +189
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2951

Could you please let me know where is the error. the code in Visual Studio is as below:
[image]

When the custom ribbon is clicked, the above code has to be triggered.

It is working in our Development environment, But getting the mentioned error in Integration, Validation and Production environments.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

PreFilledUrlLookupFiled field is causing the error. add the null condition check as below for filed.
 **this.field seems to be null.**

```
PreFilledUrlLookupField field = (PreFilledUrlLookupField)this.Field;
    if(field != null){
```

}

Answer (score 1):

My money is on this line:

```
PreFilledUrlLookupField field = (PreFilledUrlLookupField)this.Field;
```

You're passing a null value in a variable here, it seems.

Comment: In Development environment all values are coming properly. In INT environment, value is null somewhere. In INT environment from the above code, when IF condition is succeded ---> we are getting the error.
When the If condition is failed, able to open the form but lookup Value is not set.

Comment: In Development environment, we provided alerts for every step in OnLoad method. We were able to retrieve value of every parameter.  But in our Integration environment , The OnLoad method is itself failing.